# Subcript out of bounds in R

Tags: r

I am using Rstudio 2022.07.1 on Window. I am new to R and trying to sort a porfolio of stocks with the following steps:

1. I will base on a value of be_me in June of each year to sort my portfolio.
2. If the value of be_me in June is smaller than the average value of be_me in the year, I will assign the stock as "S" (small). Otherwise, the stock is considered "B" (big).

Here is the code I write, and the error is "Error in sort_size[[x]] : subscript out of bounds":

```
    for (i in seq_along(year)) {
      for (j in seq_along(month)) {
        if (j == 06) {
          average_me <- mean(be_me)
          sort_size <- vector('list', length=1)
          for (x in seq_along(be_me)) {
            if (isTRUE(x<= average_me)==TRUE) {
              sort_size[[x]] == "S"
            }else{sort_size[[x]] == "B"}
          }
        }
      }
    }

lapply(sort_size, print)
```

Could you please to show me how to fix the error as well as if you could recommend me any better way to do the task.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Please add a little bit of sample data and the desired output.

Comment: You seem to be attempting to assign "S" and "B" with a comparison operator `==` rather than the assignment operator `<-`. Since `sort_size` is length 1, when the loop assigns x a value of 2, then you are trying to compare the letter "S" or "B" to `sort_size[[2]]` which doesn't exist. I think swapping the `==` for `<-` should fix things.

Comment: You probably want sort_size[[x]] <-  rather than the second ==. In the future you should comment each line and remember that in a for-loop error you can print the loop index even after the error.

Comment: off topic but just fyi `isTRUE` alread checks for a boolean, which all math operators (like `<`, `==`, etc...) provide. The `==TRUE` part is not wrong but not necessary either.

Comment: Yeah, using the assignment operator works in my case. Thank you so much! I will also note all of your pieces of advice for my code and comment in the future.

Comment: Yeah, `if (isTRUE(x<= average_me)==TRUE)` is a long way to write `if(x <= average_me)`

Comment: when I wrote if(x <= average_me), there is an error message: "missing value when TRUE/FALSE needed". That's why I had to include the isTRUE.

Comment: Ah, okay. The `==TRUE` is still not redundant. I'd love to take a look at your problem, but it's hard to work on without sample input and the desired output. If you have sample data, you can make a copy/pasteable version of it with `dput()`, e.g., `dput(year[1:3])` for the first 3 years, `dput(be_me[1:10])` for the first 10 values of `be_me`, etc.